# Store output command in php

Tags: php, html, c

I have this C file (test.c) that I compilated and name it test.o :

```css
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void main()

{
 int i=0;
    int a=10;

 
 while(1==1)
 {
  printf("i = %d\n", i);
       printf("a = %d\n", a);
  i = i+1;
        a = a+1;
  Sleep(500);
 }
}
```

I want to display the value of each i and a in a php file. I used popen,exec,system function but the page doesn't display because I think the output doesn't stop, the page constantly is reloading.

index.php :

```html
<?php 
while (@ ob_end_flush()); // end all output buffers if any

$proc = popen("test.o", 'r');
echo '<pre>';
while (!feof($proc))
{
    $a = fread($proc, 1);;
 echo $a;
    @ flush();
}
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

How do you made it ?

Comment: I come up with java tag anything related to java?

Comment: Maybe I have to do something in java.

Comment: it's totally unclear what you actually want to do here, do you want to run both php and c scripts simulately ?

Comment: the php file is loading the c script compilated

Comment: The php file doesn't run anything, it reads the content of the .o file, which doesn't do anything, ...,

Comment: Yes I mean it read, but it can show the content of the printf no ?

Comment: First, ".o" files are not executable (you cannot execute them either with or without PHP). Second, they are not called scripts, because they are not scripts. Third, you PHP script simply reads the data from the object file. It does not execute it (and even if it tried, it wouldn't, see "first").